# K8s postgres backup failed during S3 copy

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3, kubernetes-cronjob

I am trying to backup postgres database from RDS using K8s cronjob.
I have created cronjob for it my EKS cluster and credentials are in Secrets.
When Its try to copy backup fail into AWS S3 bucket pod fails with error:
**aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:**
I tried different options but its not working.

Anybody please help in resolving this issue.
Here is brief info:
K8s cluster is on AWS EKS
Db is on RDS
I am using following config for my cronjob:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
 name: postgres-backup
 spec:
  schedule: "*/3 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 0
      template:
        spec:
          initContainers:
            - name: dump
              image: postgres:12.1-alpine
              volumeMounts:
                - name: data
                  mountPath: /backup
              args:
                - pg_dump
                - "-Fc"
                - "-f"
                - "/backup/redash-postgres.pgdump"
                - "-Z"
                - "9"
                - "-v"
                - "-h"
                - "postgress.123456789.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
                - "-U"
                - "postgress"
                - "-d"
                - "postgress"
              env:
                - name: PGPASSWORD
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      # Retrieve postgres password from a secret 
                      name: postgres
                      key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          containers:
            - name: save
              image: amazon/aws-cli
              volumeMounts:
                - name: data
                  mountPath: /backup
              args:
                - aws
                - "--version"
              envFrom:
                - secretRef:
                    # Must contain AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                    name: s3-backup-credentials
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
            - name: data
              emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: The entrypoint of the  `amazon/aws-cli:latest` image is `/usr/local/bin/aws` so what you ask your container to run is `"/usr/local/bin/aws aws --version"` and `aws` is not a valid command of the CLI.

Moreover your container is useless in this case. You should try to only dump your DB in the init container and export the dump in the init container using the aws CLI.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have tried by putting "/usr/local/bin/aws aws --version" in the args section, but still it shows same error.

Comment: No just put `--version` in the args section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
containers:
- name: save
  image: amazon/aws-cli
  ...
  args:
  - "--version"  # <-- the image entrypoint already call "aws", you only need to specify the arguments here.
...
```